# Print file out in bash

Tags: bash, file, printing

I'm looking at creating a bash script to print out a text file with some extra variables, see below

I want to have a text file with something like this in it

```
bot1
bot2
bot3
```

And then have a bash script print it out like so

```
--exclude-agent="bot1" --exclude-agent="bot2" --exclude-agent="bot3"
```

Is this possible? So that if I add another line to that first file it'll just print another --exclude-agent="whatever I put in the file"

At the moment I've got the below which is close, but not quite what I want

```
#!/bin/bash
while read line
do
echo "--exclude-agent="$line" \\"
done < bots.txt
```

Any help would be great!

Comment: http://mywiki.wooledge.org/XyProblem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends on what did you mean by

> not quite what I want

First of all, you have a problem with quoting. Correct way is

```
echo "--exclude-agent=$line \\"
```

If you want to print it on the same line try

```
echo -n "--exclude-agent=$line"
```

If you want to hold it in a variable try this code

```
params=''
while read -r line
do
    params+="--exclude-agent=$line "
done < bots.txt
printf '%s\n' "$params"
```

Also it seems like you're trying to store parameters in a variable. [Which is the worst idea ever](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050)

Answer (score 0):

`echo -n "--exclude-agent="$line"`. `-n` does not print the last `\n` so that the all options come in the same line

Answer (score 0):

to print out the expected output:

```
echo "--exclude-agent="\"$line"\" "
```